# How to attach Event Listeners to only newly created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I fire a function I want it to apply listeners just to elements I pass, particular `this` jQuery element.

```
addEventListeners(this);

function addEventListeners(el) {
        $(el).mouseenter(function() { 
            $(this).stop(true,true).switchClass("", "HIGHLIGHT", 400, "easeInOutQuad");
        });
        $(el).mouseleave(function() { 
            $(this).stop(true,true).switchClass("HIGHLIGHT", "", 400, "easeInOutQuad");
        });
    }
```

It fires from AJAX result:

```
    $.post(url,{el:wartosc_inputa},function(returned) {
        var data = $(returned).hide(); 
        $("#listaElementow").prepend(data); 
        data.slideDown();
        loading();
        addEventListeners(this);
    });
```

How to code it good? This code is not passing variables from `addEventListeners(this);` to function.

Comment: what are you trying to attach the event listeners to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the context of the rest of your success handler, I assume `returned` is the DOM element you're attempting to bind your handlers to. Assuming this is the case:

```
$.post(url,{el:wartosc_inputa},function(returned) {
    var data = $(returned).hide(); 
    $("#listaElementow").prepend(data); 
    data.slideDown();
    loading();
    addEventListeners(data[0]);
    // change this    ^^^^
    // pass the DOM element here, or 
    // change the addEventListeners function to take a jquery element
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in the ajax callback function "this" will be the ajax object i think and no longer an element so you need to save "this" in a variable before the ajax starts.

```
that = this;
$.post(url,{el:wartosc_inputa},function(returned) {
    var data = $(returned).hide(); 
    $("#listaElementow").prepend(data); 
    data.slideDown();
    loading();
    addEventListeners(that);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in that context is not what you expect it to be. Try this:

```
var self = this;
$.post(url,{el:wartosc_inputa},function(returned) {
    var data = $(returned).hide(); 
    $("#listaElementow").prepend(data); 
    data.slideDown();
    loading();
    addEventListeners(self);
});
```